# Twitter web on Iceweasel can't play video

Tags: video, debian, iceweasel

I'm using Twitter web on Iceweasel 38.2.1 (Debian unstable) and I've found it does not play videos. I don't have flash player installed but I have done the same on Firefox 40/Windows10 without flash player and it plays videos.

[image]

Does it require Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. Installing `gstreamer1.0`
2. Checking in `about:config` that `media.gstreamer.enabled` is set to true.
3. Restarting Iceweasel.

Thought had to enable h264 as well but it was not necessary. Now animated gifs and videos (mp4) are played correctly.